# MD5 based encryptor/file locker

Tags: java, oracle10g, md5

I am designing a file locker based on the MD 5 encryption technique to encode the data. I am using JAVA and oracle 10g DB.

Now, the problems I am facing is: 
1. database connectivity
2. my code works perfectly for TEXT files. But in the case of a PDF or DOC X file, it shows error.

The PDF or DOC X file is opening in the form of symbols when I am trying to access it with my program.

How do I open the WORD or PDF file in its original form?

Is it even possible to encrypt files other than TEXT files?

Comment: What do you mean by "original form"?

Comment: By "original form" i mean how we view a PDF or DOCX file when we open it normally. all the data intact. when i try to open any file other than text file with my program, it is opening in the form of symbols.

Comment: MD5 is a hashing rather than an encryption algorithm. It will absolutely be worth getting your encryption checked by security experts, to ensure it does actually protect the data in the way that you think it does. In the mean time, this question is rather broad - if you have a database connection problem, please show your database connection code, and explain how the connection problem manifests itself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why it wouldn't be, encryption is the the process of taking the original value of an object and masking it in such a way that allows only trusted individuals to retrieve the original value. You could do this with anything from text to an image to an entire hard drive. The problem you seem to be facing is mostly related to opening up a specific file type in such a way that allows you to encrypt it. But you should able to encrypt just about any file.

Comment: are PDF or DOC X files already encrypted?? is that why it is opening in the form of symbols and i am not able to encrypt it??

Comment: @Yash you are over complicating this, you are thinking of encryption in terms of plane text. Think of it instead in terms of just data, it doesn't matter if when you open the file if that data looks the same as if you open in a PDF/Docx viewer, all that matters is that you can access the data and change it, because when you decrypt it you will have the exact same data and be able to view it in a viewer. And I don't believe pdf or docx are encrypted, but even if they were it wouldn't really matter